# Android instrumentation testcases

Tags: android, instrumentation

In my instrumentation tests i have a function called

```
@SmallTest
    public void testPreconditions() {
        startActivity(mStartIntent, null, null);
        secondListView=(ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.myListView);

    }
```

For JUnit to recognize a test case does the functionname have to start with testXXXX or can i follow any convention? Is this convention configurable anywhere ?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the function name has to start with `test<function>`. This is a standard convention followed to differentiate test units from other functions. Kindly follow the same to keep your code readable and understandable by others.